# How to correct for "track jumping" for multi-lined time series

Tags: time-series, tracking

I am creating an algorithm that tries to estimate three time-series that should not cross each other (voice formants). The problem is sometimes the algorithm mistakes one time series with another and the algorithm ["jumps" track](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuFlH.png).  Here the blue line/orange line shares one track and orange line/green line also shares a track.

I was wondering if there is a name for algorithms that would fix these kinds of issue. An algorithm that estimates the best fit lines that minimize the number of sharp jumps for example. If this is a developed field I'd appreciate it if someone can point me to the right direction.

Comment: blue is on the bottom. what is "top blue"?

Comment: I edited it for clarity, I just meant the track that the blue line shares with the orange